# Editing the font color of the text inside ImageListItemBar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to using Material UI and have integrated into my portfolio website to create an ImageList that redirect to other projects I'd like to show possible employers. I'm having trouble editing the style of the text inside ImageListItemBar. I've tried using the primaryTypographyProps and sx to no avail. Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
<Typography variant="h3" color="common.red">
<ImageListItemBar
    primaryTypographyProps={{fontSize: '30px'}}
    sx={{
        background: 'black',
    }}
    position="bottom" 
    title={item.title}
/>
</Typography>
//tried this as well
<ImageListItemBar
    sx={{
        color: '#000';
        background: 'black',
    }}
    position="bottom" 
    title={item.title}
/>
```

Comment: can you show the code for imagelistitembar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code You are after:

```
<ImageListItemBar
  title="image title"
  subtitle="image subtitle"
  sx={{
    "& .MuiImageListItemBar-title": { color: "red" }, //styles for title
    "& .MuiImageListItemBar-subtitle": { color: "yellow" }, //styles for subtitle
  }}
/>
```

I recommend studying official MUI docs for [ImageList](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-image-list/) and [ImageListItemBar API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/image-list-item-bar/)

Answer (score 1):

Hamed's answer is correct, you need to target the specific class applied to the title in order to style it.

I've been developing a pattern of doing this lately, where you can import the component's classes and style accordingly using styled. This allows you to use your IDE to autocomplete the class names and target them accordingly.

```js
const StyledImageListItemBar = styled(ImageListItemBar)(() => ({
  [`& .${imageListItemBarClasses.title}`]: {
    color: "red"
  },
  [`& .${imageListItemBarClasses.subtitle}`]: {
    color: "yellow"
  },
  backgroundColor: "black"
}));
```

Then you can just use the component without having to resort to `sx`:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <StyledImageListItemBar
      title="This is a title"
      subtitle="This is a subtitle"
    />
  );
}
```

Here's a sandbox of this in action if you want to play with it: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-targetting-classes-8y5kpm?file=/src/App.js

That being said, if you're planning to reuse this component with the custom styling, I would consider overriding the default styling in theme too.